# Classifier with a vector of features and a matrix of classes

Tags: matlab, classification

I'm new in Classification so I'm asking for some advice on how to start.

I've created a Matlab script which create two matrices, one is the class identifier, meaning `100x1` which contains the group from where the data is. group one (1) or group two (2).

The second matrix contains the features `100x40` with 40 features for each point.

What's the best way to start, I'm really lost. Does Matlab has some functions I can use?

I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what version of MATLAB you are using, but the best starting point would be to look at statistics toolbox for supervised learning.  Here are some starting tips for MATLAB 2013a:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/supervised-learning.html

Let's assume that your data is

```
classes: 100x1
features: 100x40
```

For each method, the first line shows you how to fit your classification model and the second lines shows how to classify the first row of data in features.

### Statistics Toolbox

**Naive Bayes Classification**

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

```
myClassifier = NaiveBayes.fit(features, classes)
myClassifier.predict(features(1,:))
```

**Nearest Neighbors**

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_classifiers

```
myClassifier = ClassificationKNN.fit(features, classes)
myClassifier.predict(features(1,:))
```

**Classification Trees**

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_tree

```
myClassifier = ClassificationTree.fit(features, classes)
myClassifier.predict(features(1,:))
```

**Support Vector Machines**

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine

Note that Support Vector Machines moved into 2013a from Bioinformatics toolbox and it only supports classification into two groups.

```
myClassifier = svmtrain(features, classes)
svmclassify(myClassifier, features(1,:))
```

**Discriminant Analysis**

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_analysis

```
myClassifier = ClassificationDiscriminant.fit(features, classes)
myClassifier.predict(features(1,:))
```

### Neural Network Toolbox:

If you only have two classes, you could use Neural Network Toolbox for pattern recognition by typing `nnstart`